# Using sharepoint for password management?

Tags: password

I hope this is the right place to post my question.

I am looking for a way to centrally store and manage passwords for different applications and users within our company. These are not windows-accounts but shared accounts (example : application ERP uses SQL-account *John* with password *Doe* to connect to SQLServer *SQL2005*)
The goal is to provide our developers with a central location where they can find which account/password to use to what ends.

According to MoSCoW:

- M: All developers can read existing records.
- S: Only specific developers should be able to edit records.
- C: All developers can insert new records.
- W: Data is partitioned: what records are visible is decided per developer/group
- W: Records can be retrieved using a webapi

What would be the best way to do this?
A sharepoint list? A specialized app you can recommend me? An Excel-sheet protected with a password? (ugh!)

We are now using Sharepoint Online and are on the verge of migrating to Sharepoint Online 2013.

Comment: Secure Store service, if that's what you are looking for, http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/873705c1-ae28-4e92-a7ef-e6ee01d3f0a8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While SharePoint might not be the perfect solution for storing passwords, it is certainly possible to do this in a custom list (like managing any other info).

- M: break role inheritance on list/site, remove unwanted
  readers/contributors/owners and give security group containing
  Developers read permissions
- S: give selected developers (or security
  group containing these) contributor access
- C: create a custom
  permission level "Add only" that gives access to add but not edit and
  assign this to specific users or a security group (this has been
  asked
  [before](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32275/allow-users-to-submit-items-to-a-library-but-not-edit-or-delete))
- W1: Not entirely sure what you mean, but if this means that some list
  items should have special read permissions, just break role
  inheritance on them and assign special read/edit permissions.
- W2: In SPOL 2013 you have access to lists using REST. You could pass 
  [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142380.aspx) link to your developers.

Comment: Thanks! Just curious: what other solution would you suggest?

Comment: Enterprise Password Management systems that are fully compliant with SOX or other standards http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%22enterprise+password+management%22