# How to restrict all users to delete Image from Picture Library when it is referring in site

Tags: picture-library

We are referring Images from an Image Library and showing them in web parts. In case, if a user deletes any Image from back end, our web part will show empty.
Of course we can show an alternate image, but I want to restrict all the users to delete images from library while they are being referred.

Kindly help me on how to do this.

Comment: Hi Pradeep please check the link once. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32275/allow-users-to-submit-items-to-a-library-but-not-edit-or-delete Hope its help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to the Picture Library in question, and select the Shared With Button

[image]

On the modal dialogue, follow the advanced link

[image]

Click the button Stop Inherit Permissions

[image]

When you hav broken permission, you kan have the exact permission you want to have for this picture library. Select the group that you want to remove permission for (and make sure they already have read permissions from the Visitor group). Click Remove User Permission.

[image]

When you have removed all groups that have permission to delete images, you can safely add images here which you use in your webpart, without ever losing them again.

Comment: Got it...I will create a seperate group and assign permissions to that group with out delete option!!! thank you so much :)