# Can we create a custom permission level on our custom list which allow users to create items without been able to view/edit them

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, permissions, custom-permission-level

We have a custom list inside our SharePoint online >> and we want to create a custom permission level to allow users to create new items, but without been able to edit or even view them.

Is this possible? we need this as we are building an internal feedback list which allow all users to submit their feedback while only the HR team can view and edit those items.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is possible with custom permission level.

1. Copy existing contribute/edit permission level from site settings
2. Adjust the permissions by unchecking unnecessary permissions
3. Save custom permission level
4. Break permissions inheritance on SharePoint list
5. Grant permissions using custom permission level

**Similar threads**:

1. [permission to create list items but not edit them](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4e43ef90-a98e-44d1-b60c-97386ae55fd3/permission-to-create-list-items-but-not-edit-them)
2. [Allow users to submit items to a library but not edit or delete](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32275/allow-users-to-submit-items-to-a-library-but-not-edit-or-delete)
3. [Sharepoint online site permissions add but not delete](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-online-site-permissions-add-but-not/3a9d66d9-5228-4cf3-a3f2-f9df9443ff0f)

Comment: Hi @JohnGu, did you try this approach? Is it working for you??

Answer (score 0):

When you create custom permission level and select Add/Create item permission, view permission is selected by default and if you try to remove the view permission Add/Create item permission is also removed.

So what you can do is once the user create the item, break the permission of the item with the help of workflow/power automate or code(if it is custom solution) and assign unique permission on the item and do not assign any permission to that user who created the item.